# Get the previous amount of accounts?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table like this:

```
===============================
|  ID  |  Salary  |    Date   |
===============================
|  A1  |  $1000   | 2020-01-03|
-------------------------------
|  A1  |  $1300   | 2020-02-03|
-------------------------------
|  A1  |  $1500   | 2020-03-01|
-------------------------------
|  A2  |  $1300   | 2020-01-13|
-------------------------------
|  A2  |  $1500   | 2020-02-11|
-------------------------------
```

Expected output:

```
==================================================
|  ID  |  Salary  |  Previous Salary |    Date   |
==================================================
|  A1  |  $1500   |       $1300      | 2020-03-01|
--------------------------------------------------
|  A2  |  $1500   |       $1300      | 2020-02-03|
--------------------------------------------------
```

How could I query to always get their previous salary and to show in another column/table ?

Comment: please explain how their previous salary is calculated.

Comment: It does not need to calculate. It is just an example data I just made up randomly.

Comment: you can look up `LAG()` analytic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use the [`LAG` *Window Function*](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/) to reference a field from the previous record in a partitioned set (within a specified data window)

```
with [Data] as
(
    SELECT ID, Salary, Cast([Date] as Date) [Date]
    FROM (VALUES 
      ('A1', 1000, '2020-01-03'),
      ('A1',1300,'2020-02-03'),
      ('A1',1500,'2020-03-01'),
      ('A2',1300,'2020-01-13'),
      ('A2',1500,'2020-02-11')
    ) as t(ID,Salary,Date)
)
-- above is a simple demo dataset definition, your actual query is below

SELECT ID, Salary, LAG(Salary, 1) 
OVER (
    PARTITION BY [ID]
    ORDER BY [Date]
) as [Previous_Salary], [Date]
FROM [Data] 
ORDER BY [Data].[Date] DESC
```

Produces the following output:

```
ID   Salary      Previous_Salary Date
---- ----------- --------------- ----------
A1   1500        1300            2020-03-01
A2   1500        1300            2020-02-11
A1   1300        1000            2020-02-03
A2   1300        NULL            2020-01-13
A1   1000        NULL            2020-01-03

(5 rows affected)
```

Experiment with the ordering, note here in the *window* we are using *ascending* order, and in the display, we can show *descending* order.

Window functions create a virtual dataset outside of your current query, think of windows functions as a way to execute correlated queries in parallel and merge in the result.

---

In many simple implementations window functions like this should provide better or the same performance as writing your own logic to self-join or to sub query, for example this is an equivalent query using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT ID, [Data].Salary, previous.Salary as [Previous_Salary], [Data].[Date]
FROM [Data] 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 x.Salary 
             FROM [Data] x 
             WHERE x.[ID] = [Data].ID AND x.[Date] > [Data].[Date]
             ORDER BY x.[Date] DESC) as previous
ORDER BY [Data].[Date] DESC
```

The `LAG` syntax requires less code, clearly defines your intent and allows set-based execution and optimizations.

Other `JOIN` style queries will still be *blocking* queries as they will require the reversal of the original data-set (by forcing the entire set to be loaded in reverse order) and so will not offer a truly set-based or optimal approach.

SQL Server developers realized that there is genuine need for these types of queries, and that in general when left to our own devices we create inefficient lookup queries, *Window Functions* were designed to offer a best-practice solution to these types of analytical queries.

Comment: @marc-guillot has a good example using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to restrict the results to only the most recent record if you need it https://stackoverflow.com/a/60752558/1690217

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both the [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) windows functions to locate the last salary for every id and to return their last and previous salary.

```
with cte as (
  select id, salary,
         row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as position,
         lag(salary) over (partition by id order by date) as previous,
         date
  from payroll
)  
select id, salary, previous, date
from cte 
where position = 1 -- It's the first one because we ordered by date descendingly
```

Result :

```
ID    Salary                Previous              Date
----- --------------------- --------------------- ----------
A1    1500,00               1300,00               2020-03-01
A2    1500,00               1300,00               2020-02-11
```

Online sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/770472/15/0

Answer (score 0):

This query could work for you

```
select *, LAG(salary) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY id) as previous from A
```

Comment: so your query will return 5 rows instead of just 2 rows?

Comment: `ORDER BY ID, Date` would suit better.

Comment: if table contains salary records for last one year for ID A1 then above query would show every single record with previous salary which i don't think has been asked in question. Please try the query i wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Assumption: Table name 'PAYROLL' in 'PLS' schema)

```
SELECT R1.ID,R1.SALARY AS SALARY,R2.SALARY AS PREVIOUS_SALARY
FROM PLS.PAYROLL R1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PLS.PAYROLL R2 ON R1.ID=R2.ID AND R2.SALARY_DATE = (SELECT MAX(SALARY_DATE) FROM PLS.PAYROLL WHERE ID=R1.ID AND SALARY_DATE<R1.SALARY_DATE)
WHERE R1.SALARY_DATE=(SELECT MAX(SALARY_DATE) FROM PLS.PAYROLL WHERE ID=R1.ID)
ORDER BY R1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and pivot to make this.

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE (ID  VARCHAR(5),  Salary MONEY    ,[Date]  DATE)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
('A1', $1000 , '2020-01-03'),
('A1', $1300 , '2020-02-03'),
('A1', $1500 , '2020-03-01'),
('A2', $1300 , '2020-01-13'),
('A2', $1500 , '2020-02-11')

SELECT ID, [1] Salary, [2] [Previous Salary], [Date]  
FROM (SELECT ID, Salary, MAX([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS [Date], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) RN 
     FROM @SampleData ) SRC
PIVOT(MAX(Salary) FOR RN IN ([1],[2])) PVT
ORDER BY ID
```

Result:

```
ID    Salary                Previous Salary       Date
----- --------------------- --------------------- ----------
A1    1500,00               1300,00               2020-03-01
A2    1500,00               1300,00               2020-02-11
```